# Is this induced topology the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, filters

Consider the pairs $(A_i,a_i)$ where $A_i$ is a set and $a_i: U(A_i)\rightarrow A_i$ is a relation where $U(A_i)$ is denotes the set of **ultrafilters** on $A_i$.

Now consider the topological spaces $(A_i,\tau_i)$ where $\tau_i$ is the topology generated as follow:

> $U\in \tau_i \iff$ for every $x\in U$ whenever $(\mathcal{F},x)\in a_i
> $ we have $U\in \mathcal{F}$ (here $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter
>   on $A_i$). $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
>  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
>  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
>  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$

Now consider the pair $(\Pi_{i\in I}A_i, a_p)$ where $a_p: U(\Pi_{i\in I}A_i)\rightarrow \Pi_{i\in I}A_i$ is a relation between ultrafilters on the product and the product itself (as before).

Suppose that the relation $a_p$ is described as follows:

$$\big(\mathcal{F},(x_i)_{i\in I}\big)\in a_p \iff ({\pi_i}_*(\mathcal{F}),x_i) \in a_i \text{ for every } i\in I$$

Here ${\pi_i}_*(\mathcal{F}) = \{X\subseteq A_i: \pi_i^{-1}(X)\in\mathcal{F}\} $ as usual where $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter on the product.

**Question:** is the topology generated by $a_p$ on $\Pi_{i\in I}A_i$ (by using the characterization of open sets in $(*)$ in the orange block) the product topology?

*Background*: the reason I suspect this is that if $\tau$ is the product topology on $\Pi_{i\in I}A_i$, because ultrafilter convergence in the topological sense satisfies the same relation as $a_p$.

Comment: In the definition of $a_p$ on the right side shouldn't it be: $({\pi_i}_*(\mathcal{F}), x_i) \in a_i$ ? Also $i$ is not quantified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $a_i$ be the empty relation for all $i$.  Then $\tau_i$ is the discrete topology, and $a_p$ is also the empty relation (assuming $I$ is nonempty) so it induces the discrete topology as well.  But the product topology on $\prod A_i$ is not the discrete topology as long as each $A_i$ is nonempty and infinitely many of the $A_i$ have more than one point.

---

For an example where principal ultrafilters converge to the corresponding points, let $A$ be an infinite set and choose two distinct elements $s,t\in A$ and a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{G}$ on $A$.  Define a relation $a:U(A)\to A$ by saying $(\mathcal{F},x)\in a$ iff $\mathcal{F}$ is the principal ultrafilter at $x$, or $\mathcal{F}\neq\mathcal{G}$ is nonprincipal and $x=s$, or $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{G}$ and $x=t$.  Note that if $U$ is any open set containing $s$ in the induced topology, then $U$ is cofinite (since if $U$ is coinfinite, you can choose a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}\neq\mathcal{G}$ which contains $A\setminus U$ and $(\mathcal{F},s)\in a$).  In particular, it follows that with respect to the induced topology, the ultrafilter $\mathcal{G}$ converges to both $s$ and $t$, so the induced topology is not Hausdorff.

Now consider the product relation $a_p$ on $A\times A$.  I claim that the set $\Delta=\{(x,x):x\in A\}$ is closed in the topology induced by $a_p$.  Indeed, suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter on $A\times A$ such that $\Delta\in\mathcal{F}$.  For any $X\subseteq A$, $(X\times A)\cap \Delta=(A\times X)\cap\Delta$, and it follows that ${\pi_0}_*(\mathcal{F})={\pi_1}_*(\mathcal{F})$.  Thus if $\mathcal{F}$ converges to a point $(x,y)$ according to $a_p$, then the ultrafilter ${\pi_0}_*(\mathcal{F})={\pi_1}_*(\mathcal{F})$ converges to both $x$ and $y$ according to $a$.  Since no ultrafilter converges to two different points according to $a$, this means $x=y$, so $(x,y)\in\Delta$.  Thus $\Delta$ is closed in the topology induced by $a_p$.  However, $\Delta$ is not closed in the product topology since the topology on $A$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Can the second example be made to work for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374455/4280), perhaps? It's for convergence spaces for filters, not only ultrafilters, don't know if that matters much..

Comment: Would it change the example much we also let the principal filters at $s$ and $t$ converge to $s$ resp. $t$? This is often in axiom in ultrafilter-convergence spaces.

Comment: (1) I'm not quite sure what you mean by "work".  If you mean it gives a convergence space in which no proper filter has more than one limit but the induced topology is not Hausdorff, then yes, it works.  (2) That is included in the example.  $(\mathcal{F},x)\in a$ if $\mathcal{F}$ is the principal ultrafilter at $x$, including the cases $x=s$ and $x=t$.

Comment: OK, I see. But what would the convergence be in terms of a relation between filters and points?

Comment: A filter converges to $x$ iff every ultrafilter containing it converges to $x$.

Comment: Is that a standard construction? It probably is. Are convergence spaces in terms of filters (with the fixed filter axiom, closure under finite intersections and enlargement) totally equivalent to ultrafilter convergence spaces with the fixed filter axiom? I've never seen a discussion of this..

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen it written down, but it is the way convergence of filters and convergence of ultrafilters are related for topological spaces, so it is the obvious construction to make.  However, I don't believe filter convergence spaces are equivalent to ultrafilter convergence spaces: in a filter convergence space, it is possible to have a filter which does not converge to a point even though every ultrafilter containing it does.

Comment: For instance, if you declare that every nonprincipal ultrafilter converges to a point, the axioms of a convergence space only let you deduce that finite intersections of ultrafilters converge to that point, not that the cofinite filter converges to that point.

Comment: and what about if you allow arbitrary intersections (a so-called pretopological space)?

Comment: Then using ultrafilters and using filters is equivalent, since every filter is the intersection of the ultrafilters containing it.

Comment: What is the topology on $A$ induced by the convergence? I suppose all cofinite subsets containing $s$, all subsets from $\mathcal{G}$ containing $t$, and all subsets of $A\setminus\{s,t\}$ I think?

Comment: Do you know a standard convergence space with this property, i.e. that no proper filter converges to more than one point, but the induced topology is not Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct about what the induced topology is.  What do you mean by "standard"?

Comment: as a relation that specifies convergence for filters satisfying the three axioms [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space).

Comment: Yes, just take the example I gave in the answer and define a filter to converge to $x$ if every ultrafilter extending it converges to $x$.

Comment: so the cofinite filter does not converge, it seems, as it can be extended to both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. And the filter generated by $\{s,t\}$ converges to both these points. I was hoping to keep the unique convergence property.

Comment: Yes, the cofinite filter does not converge.  And the filter generated by $\{s,t\}$ does not converge either, since the filter generated by $\{s\}$ converges only to $s$ and the filter generated by $\{t\}$ converges only to $t$.